# Deploying Node.js app with Heroku throws "Process exited with status 132" error

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have made a REST API for my chat-app. I am trying to deploy it on Heroku, the API runs perfectly with "Heroku local". I have trying to find a way to solve this for 2 months now.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found a similar issue [Github Issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3920).

The issue is supposedly patched in Node.js v12.1.0.

Could you try updating your Node.js version to atleast v12.1.0 if your version is earlier.

Comment: I am using using node 14.16.1.